# Can't change selectedIndex on select with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, selectedindex

http://info.academyart.edu/programs?&pmcode=PMDIR

On this page, when you choose any option from "Current level of education" select, an new select is shown below ("Program of interest").

I'm trying to change it's value via my chrome extension like this:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
var program = document.getElementById('Program');
program.selectedIndex = 1;
evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
program.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

but it won't change. I tried also with this:

```
var program = document.getElementById('Program');
program.selectedIndex = 1;
```

but result is the same.

In my code I first select an value in "current level of education" selectbox, if that matters.
So, I can change value in any other select on that page, but I can't change it on this one.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That `<select>` doesn't have any options other than the title until after the user selects the education level. Then all the options get added by Javascript. I suspect your extension is running before the options get added.

Comment: How can I "wait" for Javascript in my chrome extension to add options to this select, and then select one of them?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you should run your code in the `change` event listener for the education dropdown, after the page's own `change` listener runs.

Comment: I try with this, but no result. It prints "lol" to the console though, as a confirmation that change event is registered..
var educationLevel = document.getElementById('educationLevel');
educationLevel.addEventListener("change", function() {
            var program = document.getElementById('Program');
            program.selectedIndex = 1;
            console.log("lol");
});
        educationLevel.selectedIndex = 1;

Comment: Why are you assigning `educationLevel.selectedIndex`?

Comment: Did you think that would trigger the `change` event? The event is only triggered when the menu is changed through the UI, not through a script.

Comment: I don't know if, or how, you can ensure that your listener runs after the listener on the real page.

Comment: It triggers it actually. I'm not using UI at all.

Comment: Does the Program menu display when you do that? Add `console.log(educationLevel.options.length)` to the event listener, what does it show?

Comment: Yes it does.
Console.log outputs 11, just as it should

Comment: Sorry, I meant `program.options.length`.

Comment: So your listener is running before the one on the page that adds the options. Like I said before, I don't know how to make sure yours runs after that one.

Comment: OK, thanks for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatching events is only useful when something listens to them. The element in question (`#educationLevel`) listens to `focus`, `change`, and `blur` events.

The easiest way to create events is with an `Event` constructor.

```
function dispatch(el, evType) {
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event(evType));
}

var level = document.getElementById('educationLevel');
dispatch(level, 'focus');
level.selectedIndex = 1;
dispatch(level, 'change');
dispatch(level, 'blur');
```

However, `#Program` only listens to `focus` and `blur` so you don't need to dispatch the `change` event.

**The actual problem**: `#Program` is empty on load and only gets populated after `change` on `#educationLevel` fires. Thus you need to apply a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on it:

```
function initMO(root, callback) {
    var MO = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
    var observer = new MO(function(mutations) {
        observer.disconnect();
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            callback(mutation.target);
        });
        observe(); // comment this out to run only once
    });
    var opts = { childList: true, subtree: true };
    var observe = function() {
        observer.takeRecords();
        observer.observe(root, opts);
    };
    observe();
}
```

---

full solution:

```
function dispatch(el, evType) {
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event(evType));
}
function addMO(root, callback) {
    var MO = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
    var observer = new MO(function(mutations) {
        observer.disconnect();
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            callback(mutation.target);
        });
        observe(); // comment this out to run only once
    });
    var opts = { childList: true, subtree: true };
    var observe = function() {
        observer.takeRecords();
        observer.observe(root, opts);
    };
    observe();
}

var level = document.getElementById('educationLevel');
dispatch(level, 'focus');
level.selectedIndex = 1;
dispatch(level, 'change');
dispatch(level, 'blur');

var program = document.getElementById('Program');
addMO(program, function() {
    program.selectedIndex = 1;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't get selected neither that way.. If I insert 
        console.log(program.options.length);

after dispatch(program, 'focus');

it outputs 0

Comment: @kecman you replied before I finalized the solution. Reread the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page, your content script is injected and you can view from F12 tool, at that time #Program is hidden with only one option. So after the rest options showing, you content script will not be injected and executed again, that's the root cause.

You should try executing

```
program.selectedIndex = 1;
```

after the hidden options show, for example, you can declare a browserActionListener in your background script and do messaging communication when click that, then you can make sure above code be executed in an environment that the rest options can be accessed.

Comment: I understand first part of your answer, I came to that conclusion myself, but I don't really understand second one. My intention is to fill whole form with my extension, so there won't be any click event on form.